# How to find out where a domain resolves to

Tags: domain

Hi,

lets say threre is a site called mypage.com but I want to find out whats the actual URL where domain resolves to. It usually is something like 123.45.67/~mypage/www. How will you do it?

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you looking for this? Such an alternative "actual" URL (which isn't the actual URL) does not exist for most web sites.

Comment: Its an address from which you can always reach the website no matter if the domain is suspended.

Comment: Again, no such address may exist. It would only do if the site were specifically configured for it. There is no way to predict these; it requires knowledge of the server configuration.

Comment: I have had many websites hosted on different servers and the actual address always look like in my example so I dont know why you say that.

Comment: I say it because it is true. That is all.

Comment: I will wait for a second opinion, then.

Comment: You'll have to wait a very, very long time if you want to hear something different. The sun will burn out first.

Comment: If somebody else comes here and confirms what you say then I might believe it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton is correct.

Comment: Nobody cares what you believe.  This is a tech site and these are the facts.

Comment: @CainNuke is the reason I have no trust in "webdevelopers"

Comment: @CainNuke The upvotes on his comments are second third and fourth opinions.

Answer (score 7):

@michaelhampton is correct, you cannot know this information from outside. The reason for this is that you need to know the server configuration and the server needs to have been configured to respond to requests in the manner that you want.

I suspect your system has been configured with some sort of [mass virtual hosting](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/mass.html) rather than individual vhosts.

Answer (score 1):

**How will you do it?** - Under normal circumstances you can't. As everyone else has said, this is just not normally possible.

The reason for this is because it is a security vulnerability that people protect against. And attempting to find out what the path is could actually be seen as trying to hack in to the site, or at least gather information that may be useful for hacking the site!

Sites do occasionally have this vulnerability: For example, sometimes web servers are configured to show verbose errors. In this case, if the web server encounters an error condition it may reveal the path you are talking about. Or if the web page happens to have the path published on it (no doubt due to a programming error or other mistake). Or if there is some other bug that allows you to dig a bit deeper to find out the path.

If you need to test a site for this, then there is a tool that can do it. Do not use this tool on a site that you are not authorised to use it on.
https://github.com/Occupy4Elephants/inspathx

Detailed explanation of why people avoid this functionality:
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Full_Path_Disclosure

Answer (score -4):

To know where a domain is resolved to you can use the online tool  http://intodns.com/ It provides information about Nameservers, mail server and pointing server IP address.

Comment: Thank you but this only gives me the IP. I need the full path that takes me to the website as an alternative to the domain.

Comment: @CainNuke AGAIN, there is not such standard.